# SQL Azure Full text low performance

Tags: full-text-search, azure-sql-database

I have a table with 150K rows. In a local server this query responds in 32 s

```
SELECT *
FROM file_ocr
WHERE CONTAINS(contents, '"ofi*" AND NOT "digi*"');
GO
```

but in SQL Azure (Production) responds in 8 minutes. DTU % is about 65%.

This performance is usual? This is the table & catalog creation:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[full_text](
[client_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[file_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[page_number] [int] NULL,
[contents] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_full_text] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [ID] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =    OFF,         ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) 
ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

create fulltext catalog dd_full_text;
GO

create fulltext index on full_text(contents)
key index PK_full_text on dd_full_text with change_tracking auto
GO
```

I tried rebuilding and reorganizing the index but I get no favorable results.

Comment: What tier of SQL are you using in Azure? For instance if your on Standard S0 you only get 10 DTUs, so 65% would be 6.5. However, using a S1 would give you 20 DTUs and cost around double what a S0 would. Have you tried increasing the tier even as a temporary measure to see if it improves performance.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your quick answer. This is my plan: 
 DTU % – ~70% (from Azure graphics)
 North Europe
 Server version: V12
 S3 standard (100 DTUs)

Comment: Ok so, have you tried upping the plan to the next level? I'm not a DBA but also have you tried looking at the following page to see if your query can be improved or the indexes improved using the Index Advisor? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/full-text-search-is-now-available-for-preview-in-azure-sql-database/

Comment: Hi, Index Advisor doesn't recommend any index creation :S I will check if upping the plan I get better performance ;)

Comment: Well index advisor not recommending anything is a good thing, just proves your database is designed efficiently.

Comment: I have upgraded the plan to 125DTUS but I see no aparently differences. Should I rebuild the catalog?

Comment: Always worth a go.

Comment: Still not working :S I get the same results in Standard 3 and Premium 1. :S

Comment: I would suggest logging a support ticket as something doesn't seem right, are you noticing the DTU usage go down with the higher tier?

Comment: Thank you very much Martyn. I will create a ticket. I will let you know the results ;)